# comparing digit by digit two columns in a dataframe using spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    [123, 123],
    [111, 111],
    [124, 125],
    [111, 333],
    [123, 223],
    [111, 211]
  ],['col1','col2'])
```

I need to compare two columns and identify the number of digits not matching between two columns using pyspark

Comment: why do you want to compare digit by digit, you can compare full digit like 124 == 125 ?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
adf.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)


adf.selectExpr("col1","col2","(col1 == col2) as compared").show()
+----+----+--------+
|col1|col2|compared|
+----+----+--------+
| 123| 123|    true|
| 111| 111|    true|
| 124| 125|   false|
| 111| 333|   false|
| 123| 223|   false|
| 111| 211|   false|
+----+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced this problem.

Probably there's a more proper solution using arrays in pyspark, but here we go:

**SAME LENGTH SOLUTION**: converting digits to strings and then comparing them element-wise gave me what I wanted, but numbers must have the same length:

```py
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def count_digit_shifts(str1, str2):
    return sum([1 for char1, char2 in zip(str(str1), str(str2)) if char1 != char2])

df1 = df1.withColumn('digit_diff', count_digit_shifts('col1', 'col2'))
df1.show()
```

this will give you

```
+----+----+----------+
|col1|col2|digit_diff|
+----+----+----------+
| 123| 123|         0|
| 111| 111|         0|
| 124| 125|         1|
| 111| 333|         3|
| 123| 223|         1|
| 111| 211|         1|
+----+----+----------+
```

However, if the numbers have different lengths:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    [1232, 123],
    [111, 1111],
    [124, 125],
    [111, 333],
    [123, 223],
    [1110, 211]
  ],['col1','col2'])
```

there are two possibilities:

- Left padding: numbers added to your right just add more digit differences (useful for number sequences). It's also the proper solution for string columns:

```py
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def count_digit_shifts(str1, str2):
    return sum([1 for char1, char2 in zip(str(str1), str(str2)) if char1 != char2])\
           + abs(len(str(str2)) - len(str(str1)))
```

- Right padding: proper solution for numbers

```py
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def count_digit_shifts(str1, str2):
    str1 = str(str1)
    str2 = str(str2)
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        max_length = max(len(str1),len(str2))
        str1 = str1.rjust(max_length, '0')
        str2 = str2.rjust(max_length, '0')
    return sum([1 for char1, char2 in zip(str1, str2) if char1 != char2])
```

Hope this helps